# Reputation decreased due to removal of random post

Tags: support

My reputation was decreased. When I look at the reason it says that the post was removed. But I don't think that I was by any means connected to that post. Has this happened to anybody else?

Or do I need to know something about Stack Overflow?

Comment: You had a suggested edit on a question that was recently deleted by an automated process.